# How do i add a button to change a value in a URL

Tags: php, json, html

I have a php page that gets generated from JSON, but i cant find a way to make buttons to go to other pages.
Currently i have to define the page in the URL and change it by hand every time.
I also have a other value in my URL that i don't want to get deleted.
How do i do this.
I currently have tryed:

- Zebra_Pagination
- onassar/PHP-Pagination
  but they require a sql database which i don't use

here is the current code i have and i already for design reasons added the Buttons.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Blackout Media Partner Search tool</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="/css/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Marcel
 * Date: 5/23/2015
 * Time: 7:04 PM
 */

 $keyword = $_GET['keyword']; 
 $page = $_GET['page'];
 if($page == 0) {
     $start = 1;
 } else {
    $start = $page * 10;
 }
 echo '<center><h2>Blackout Media channel search tool</h2></center>';
 echo '<nav>
  <ul class="pager">
    <li class="previous"><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> Previous Page</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Page ' . $page . '</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Start ' . $start . '</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Keyword ' . $keyword . '</a></li>
    <li class="next"><a href="#">Next Page <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>';
    echo'<div class="panel panel-primary">';
    echo '<div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Search</h3></div>';
    echo '<div class="panel-body">';
    echo '<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="input-group"><center>
        <form action="/" method="GET">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." name="keyword">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
  <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form></center>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>';
function AddDecimals($number, $dec_point='.', $thousands_sep=','){
    if($dec_point==$thousands_sep){
        trigger_error('2 parameters for ' . __METHOD__ . '() have the same value, that is "' . $dec_point . '" for $dec_point and $thousands_sep', E_USER_WARNING);
        // It corresponds "PHP Warning:  Wrong parameter count for number_format()", which occurs when you use $dec_point without $thousands_sep to number_format().
    }
    if(preg_match('{\.\d+}', $number, $matches)===1){
        $decimals = strlen($matches[0]) - 1;
    } else {
        $decimals = 0;
    }
    return number_format($number, $decimals, $dec_point, $thousands_sep);
}

$jsonContents = file_get_contents('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/channels/?q='.$keyword.'&start-index='.$start.'&v=2&&max-results=10&alt=json');

$json = json_decode($jsonContents, true);
//var_dump($json);
foreach($json['feed']['entry'] as $feed) {
    echo '<br>';
    echo'<div class="panel panel-primary">';
    echo '<div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title"> Channel: '. $feed['title']['$t'] . '</h3></div>';
    echo '<div class="panel-body">';
    echo '<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
  <li role="presentation"><a target="_blank" href="'. $feed['link'][1]['href'].'">Youtube</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a target="_blank" href="https://channelmeter.com/search/?q='. $feed['yt$channelId']['$t'] .'">ChannelMeter</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a target="_blank" href="http://vidooly.com/search/'. $feed['yt$channelId']['$t'] .'">Vidooly</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="disabled"><a href="#">SocialBlade</a></li>
</ul>';
    echo '<ul class="list-group">';
    echo '<li class="list-group-item">Channel Name: '. $feed['title']['$t'] . '</li>';
    echo '<li class="list-group-item">Channel Description: '. $feed['summary']['$t'] . '</li>';
    echo '<li class="list-group-item">Channel ID: '. $feed['yt$channelId']['$t'] . '</li>';
    echo '<li class="list-group-item">Subscribers: '. AddDecimals($feed['yt$channelStatistics']['subscriberCount']) . '</li>';
    echo '<li class="list-group-item">Views: '. AddDecimals($feed['yt$channelStatistics']['viewCount']) . '</li>';
    echo '<li class="list-group-item">Channel Link: <a href='. $feed['link'][1]['href'].'>'. $feed['link'][1]['href'].'</a>' .'</li>';
    echo '<li class="list-group-item">Last Update: '. $feed['updated']['$t'] . '</li>';
    echo '<li class="list-group-item disabled">User ID: '. $feed['author']['yt$userId']['$t'] . '</li>';
        echo '<li class="list-group-item disabled">Partner Status: '. $feed['author']['yt$userId']['$t'] . '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo ' </div>';
    echo '<br>';
}
 echo '<nav>
  <ul class="pager">
    <li class="previous"><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> Previous Page</a></li>
        <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Page ' . $page . '</a></li>
    <li class="next"><a href="#">Next Page <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>';
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery call a function in the button click, then

```
parent.location.hash = "hello";
```

You can have this

```
<button id="trigger">Change url</button>
```

And when the above button triggers it will call the following script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#trigger").click(function(){
parent.location.hash = "hello";
});
});
</script>
```

And it will change your url without reloading the page or typing manually.

You can have anything in the url i.e., `#value` or your subdomain or anything you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the code.
Im not sure how to inplement it and the value im using dont have a # on it
here is a example of how i have it working
https://youtube-xml-to-php-inpothet.c9.io/?keyword=minecraft&page=5

Comment: Welcome. I saw the url, Here you want to place the value entered in the search box to be placed in the  url ?

Comment: The search box works but the problem as i only load 10 of the 1k+ responses i wanted to make it use pages
so basicly when i add the &page=2 it will do 2* 10 and output that in the request url towards the API.
im trying to make buttons that will increase the 2 to a 3 and so forth and also to the opposite way till 0

Comment: If i understand properly.. Is this your need.. **You need to have pagination without page refresh**  i.e., once clicked in the button on the Next Page it will load the next 10 items.. Am i right ?

Comment: Yes you are right
and to be honest page refresh doesnt mather for me to mush, but i think it is needed as the value in the url is send in the request to the api.

Comment: and again thank you for your help i'm still new at coding in php and json and don't know a thing of jquery or javascript

Comment: Yes i can understand you .. And can you say this. If the value in the url was changed whether you'l call the api ?

Comment: Shall i suggest you any plugin that handles pagination ? by itself ?

Comment: Yes that would be handy i hope i get it working not like the last 2 things
again thank you for your help

Comment: You can try [this](http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/#example-simple) or [this](http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/#demo) plugin .. I personally suggest you to use [datables](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) which has n number features than we imagine. I am using it for all my needs :) It has pagination, sorting, searching and many other functionalities.. You need to have only 4 lines of code to implement it

Comment: I would like to use a database but i dont want to use sesions as i want this to be used by multiple people
and i will try those again thank you
and by any change you dont know any json do you ?

Comment: It is DATATABLES Here is the link https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html It is a plugin which will handle all the operations that we need. i.e., pagination without page refresh and lot...

Comment: I have looked at the plugins and at datatables and sofar i have seen that i cant use datatables as i dont use a table to load or save anything
i will take a look athe the plugins

Comment: Oh.. That's ok.. So you want to send these two parameters to the plugin `keyword=minecraft&page=5` ?

Comment: In the next page `keyword=minecraft&page=10` and `keyword=minecraft&page15` like that ??

Comment: Yes but someone els that direct contacted me has fixed it
This is the current code
  $pageUp = $page + 1;
  $pageDown = $page - 1;
<a href="?keyword=' . $keyword . '&page=' . $pageDown . '">Previous Page</a>

Comment: And now the issue is fixed ?

Comment: Yes the issue is now fixed
and im keeping your code in as i can use it as a example when i want to change it to javascript.